# Increasing the width of a panel on click in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Please i need help i am trying to increase the size of a panel onclick just like a vertical navigation bar with vb.net

```
    Public Class AdminPanel

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Label4.Text = "Menu" Then
            Panel1.Width = 212
            Label4.Text = "Back"
        End If
        If Label4.Text = "Back" Then
            Panel1.Width = 71

            Label4.Text = "Menu"
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AdminPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: And what happens when you click that button?

Comment: the size of the panel does not increase on click neither decrease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Else if for the second part of your button click otherwise the same method resets the label name back to its original value

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Label4.Text = "Menu" Then
        Panel1.Width = 212
        Label4.Text = "Back"
        ' Done for this click --- do not check if the label text
        ' is Back you have just changed it
    Else If Label4.Text = "Back" Then
        Panel1.Width = 71

        Label4.Text = "Menu"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can i add some kind of slow transition effect as its width increase?

Comment: Please post a new question. In this way more people will be able to see your request, but I suggest you to try something before and ask when you have a problem with the new code